# Highlighted Large Item In RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I have been working since a long time with RecyclerView. See my concept:

[image]

Main highlighted item should be in the centre (1st item can be an exception). As the user scroll, highlighted item's size should decrease and next item size starts increasing with an animation. Hope it's understandable.

Any tutorials or hints regarding this approach?

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) ?

And [this](https://hackmd.io/s/r1IEQ-jAl) is the full of tutorial that you can follow

Comment: Simple item animators allow sizing problem solution?

Answer (score 0):

Following article may be helpful for you:

[Custom Recycler view and features the first item which is at top.](https://blog.mindorks.com/hack-that-recyclerview-f6b8238e68ec)

[Github link](https://github.com/developer-shivam/FeaturedRecyclerView)

Illustration gif:

[image]

Comment: Seems good but someone has posted an issue there that he can't expand last few items and this issue hasn't fixed yet.

Comment: Yes, it's just for a reference to help you build your own solution. 